# scrapy item: when to return them?

Tags: parsing, return, scrapy

Here is the problem:

1. I can find Item data in A webpage, then follow the outlinks of A to
   get additional Item data.
2. The additional Item data is in B and C webpage. There is a `parse_b()`
   for B, an `parse_c()` for C (These two parse are callback in
   parse_A()). After this Item data is complete.

So, in which `parse()` return the item?

Comment: You return the Item in the last callback: parse_a return Request(callback parse_b)... parse_b return Request(callback parse_c)... parse_c return Item.

Comment: It works,but is there any better method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look towards https://github.com/darkrho/scrapy-inline-requests

It seems like this:

```
class FooSpider(BaseSpider):
    @inline_request
    def parse_a(self, response):
        l = FooLoader()
        l.add_value("A", "A")
        b = yield Request(response.url + '/b)
        l.add_value("B", b)
        c = yield Request(response.url + '/c)
        l.add_value("C", c)
        yield l.load_item()

    @inline_request
    def parse_b(self, response):
        # Doing what you want
        return "B"

    @inline_request
    def parse_c(self, response):
        # Doing what you want
        return "C"
```